# What is the keyboard shortcut for switching branches?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Almost everything can be done in VS Code using the keyboard, which I love, but I cannot find out how to change branches but for clicking on the branch name in the bottom right corner.

An internet search brought up very little, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If it's not in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), then there isn't one.

Comment: The issue was that I didn't understand that this function was called `Git: Checkout to`, now I know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using git, you can go to `keyboard shortcuts` by going to preferences -> keyboard shortcuts and search for `Git: Checkout to` and change this to your prefered shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use git switch and push command.

Actually I've found out it's:

```
git switch <Branch_Name>
```

If you want to push:

```
git push
```

That's my used case :)

Comment: I think original question was about VS code IDE, but you provided commands to simple bash terminal. So this won't help the author